# Cached web page no more available on Google

Tags: cache, google-search

In these days I noticed that the option cache is no more available in Google research. Until few days ago, the option was in the drop-down menu, below "Feedback", that appears when you click on the three dots near the link of a website.

Could you tell me if this option is still accesible maybe in another way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The other way to get the same result consists to write the operator "cache:" before the link.

Example: [cache:https://archive.org](https://cache:https://archive.org)